# Wordpress Headers Already Sent

Tags: php, wordpress

I appreciate this question has been asked to the nth degree but I can't seem to fix it going through the answers out there.

If anyone has any idea what is causing this I would greatly appreciate it.

I'm building a wordpress site on a localhost using WAMP to test a few things before going live. I have installed the Insert PHP plug in and it keeps causing this error:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie – headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:237) in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\insert-php\insert_php.php(48) : eval()’d code on line 2

I've checked all relevant PHP files for white spaces, checked the encoding and it still keeps happening. I've taken the close tags off the documents and still can't seem to fix it.

I can only think this is something to do with WordPress or am I being really ignorant to something?

EDIT:

The code is:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
 }

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

//set validation error flag as false
$error = false;

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);

//name can contain only alpha characters and space
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
    $error = true;
    $name_error = "Name must contain only alphabets and space";
}
if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error = true;
    $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
}
if(strlen($password) < 6) {
    $error = true;
    $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
}
if($password != $cpassword) {
    $error = true;
    $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
}
if (!$error) {
    if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(name,email,password) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . md5($password) . "')")) {
        $successmsg = "Successfully Registered! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";
    } else {
        $errormsg = "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What PHP are you trying to insert? If you're trying to add `session_start()` then you probably can't use this plugin to do it. It's impossible for us to know without seeing what code you're trying to add, and where.

Comment: This seems a bit off for WordPress to be doing this - I have worked with it for years and not had it happen to me. It will be a plugin no doubt, go through them all and disable them one by one. find it. Get rid of it.

Comment: Have you tried to find the place with http://php.net/manual/de/function.headers-sent.php

Comment: Thanks so far guys, it is the session_start() function causing the problem as best as I can tell.

Answer (score -1):

No it is likely that this error is caused by a plugin or theme. You may be misinterpreting the error message because WordPress uses an Action-Driven approach. The author of the plugin likely used a hook which runs too late to do the session stuff he needs to do or another plugin or theme on your WordPress is not coded properly. We need more information to solve this problem.